# Android rest web services call, Connections refuse issue

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I'm developing a android application and calling REST web services.It gives a error
This is my log

```
05-31 12:23:34.355: W/System.err(766): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://myip:8084 refused  
05-31 12:23:34.365: W/System.err(766): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)  
05-31 12:23:34.365: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-31 12:23:34.365: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-31 12:23:34.365: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-31 12:23:34.375: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)  
05-31 12:23:34.375: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-31 12:23:34.375: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-31 12:23:34.375: W/System.err(766):  at com.example.locationtracker.RestWSUser.sendThroughHttpGet(RestWSUser.java:38)
05-31 12:23:34.375: W/System.err(766):  at com.example.locationtracker.MainActivity.checkIn(MainActivity.java:38)
05-31 12:23:34.375: W/System.err(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 12:23:34.375: W/System.err(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 12:23:34.385: W/System.err(766):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
05-31 12:23:34.385: W/System.err(766):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-31 12:23:34.385: W/System.err(766):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-31 12:23:34.395: W/System.err(766):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-31 12:23:34.395: W/System.err(766):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 12:23:34.395: W/System.err(766):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 12:23:34.395: W/System.err(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-31 12:23:34.395: W/System.err(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 12:23:34.395: W/System.err(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 12:23:34.395: W/System.err(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-31 12:23:34.405: W/System.err(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-31 12:23:34.405: W/System.err(766):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 12:23:34.405: W/System.err(766): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-31 12:23:34.415: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:181)
05-31 12:23:34.415: W/System.err(766):  ... 22 more
05-31 12:23:34.415: W/System.err(766): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-31 12:23:34.435: W/System.err(766):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:583)
05-31 12:23:34.435: W/System.err(766):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
05-31 12:23:34.435: W/System.err(766):  at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:663)
05-31 12:23:34.445: W/System.err(766):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:807)
05-31 12:23:34.445: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-31 12:23:34.445: W/System.err(766):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
05-31 12:23:34.445: W/System.err(766):  ... 22 more
05-31 12:23:34.455: W/System.err(766): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-31 12:23:34.465: W/System.err(766):  at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
05-31 12:23:34.465: W/System.err(766):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
```

This is my java code

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://myip:8084/rest/loc/test/7225");
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30000);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder responseStr = new StringBuilder();
    String responseLineStr = null;
    while ((responseLineStr = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        responseStr.append(responseLineStr);
    }
```

This is my Manifest file permission list

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

What can be the reason for this, services are working
Thanks

Comment: are you checking this on emulator or on device? and have you checked that url on browser? also check does it need any authentication or parameter and you are sending properly..

Comment: I'm checking this on emulator, and this url is properly working in my browser, and the same URL i'm giving to this code also. There is no authentication from web services side, but i don't know about android section.  Thanks

Comment: no that is not the case like android needs to send any authentication for Rest (any kind of api/web services). try debugging code and check once.

Comment: Those web services created by myself and same issue occur when i try this using my local  web service IP, are you still think that, there should be some authentication issues ?

Comment: The exception came at HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet); line

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing the emulator with `myip`, give `10.0.2.2`. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue, this was a permission issue, its really like a syntax issue you all can see it in my first post, at  Manifest file

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

is wrong, it should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Thanks for all replies, and sorry for my mistake